# Upgrade python 3.4.3 to 3.5.1, problems with Pip

Tags: upgrade, python, pip

I'm trying to upgrade my python version.

I was able to download and install python 3.5.1 and set his alias to python4

```
root@test:/# python4
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 18 2015, 16:31:51)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Now I have problems with Pip. 
Reading another question they said to install pip like this:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python4 get-pip.py
```

This worked and I can use pip like this

```
pip3.5 install [...]
```

I'm trying to install pyCrypto for example, and I get this error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3.5m -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-exks3job/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6gya6m9i-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-exks3job/pycrypto/
```

How can resolve this Pip problem?

Or how can I make a clean installation on python 3.5 and remove python 3.4?

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use? Python 3.5 is available in APT repository for 16.04.

Comment: Forgot the version, I'm using Ubuntu 15.04. It had preinstalled python 3.4.3

Comment: @Fre 15.04 has gone EOL. Consider upgrading to 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by myself. It seems that I didn't have the "python3.5-dev" installed.

Solved using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```